# How to make a commutative diagram with 16 rectangles and to take not more than half a page?

Tags: color, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

Here is the code I am using:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
 \usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}

\[ 
\begin{tikzcd}[sep=large]
  M \rar \dar["\mathrm{Pinch}" ' ]  \arrow[dr, dashed, "\beta_1 + \beta_2 + \beta_3 = 0", sloped] & * \rar \dar & \Sigma M \dar \rar & \Sigma M \dar \\%
M \vee M \vee M \rar[swap, "{(\beta_1 , \beta_2 , \beta_3)}" ] & N \rar & N' \rar & \Sigma M \vee \Sigma M \vee \Sigma M \rar[swap, "{(\beta_1 , \beta_2 , \beta_3)}" ] & N \rar & N' \rar & \Sigma M \vee \Sigma M \vee \Sigma M 
\end{tikzcd}
\]
```

But this code gives the figure below:

[image]

So, I want to know how to make this commutative diagram have 16 rectangles and to take not more than half a page?

Also I want to color every third down arrow with green

Any help will with this will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show a sketch of the expected output. How are these 16 rectangles supposed to be arranged. You also mention wanting the diagram to take up less than half a page. Does that refer to widthwise or lengthwise?

Comment: For green colored downwars-pointing arrows, you can use `\dar[green]` instead of `\dar`.

Comment: @leandriis just beside each other, like in the above given figure I have only 3 rectangles but I want to draw 16. Lenghtwise.

Comment: @leandriis thank you!

Comment: Unless you quite drastically decrease the margin size and/or use a landscape oriented page, I'm pretty surre 16 rectangle sina single line won't fit, even if you use a quite small font size.

Comment: Even if each rectangle is less than 2cm wide, sixteen of them will take 32cm. How to fit an elephant in a suitcase?

Comment: you need to rethink design of your diagram. Do you realy need all nodes? One possible solution is to split it into two (or three) parts.

Comment: @leandriis 16 rectangles not in a single line, in half a page. like for example 4 rectangles in the first line and so on until 4 rectangles in the fourth line.

Comment: Yeah I can split it into 3 or 4 parts, each part in a single line. @Zarko

Comment: @Happy: This misunderstanding is precisely why I asked for a sketch of the expected output. Your statement "just beside each other" made me (and apparently others, too) think you wanted to draw all 16 rectangles in a single row.

Comment: I am so sorry for that. I do not mean that, next time I will sketch my figure with paint. The thing is that I usually sketch my figure with a pen and then take a photo and usually the photo has a very large size and can not be uploaded.@leandriis

Comment: You could use standalone class to show the complete diagram.

Comment: @Happy: A photo of a hand-drawn sketch it perfectly fine. In order to upload it, you could crop it and/or decrease its resolution in order to get a smaller file size.

Comment: @JohnKormylo how can I do this?

Comment: @leandriis ok, thank you! yeah I had to use another program to decrease its size.

Comment: Simply replace "article" with "standalone".  You might need to load the standalone package.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Just doing this? Nothing more?

Comment: @Happy Just try John's recommendation - that's quicker than asking :)

Comment: @JohnKormylo I did that but it did not compile and gave me an error

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner  I did that but it did not compile and gave me an error

Comment: @JohnKormylo can you please show me exactly the code?

Comment: See the second example in section *3.2 Tweaking to paths*, page 12, Ti*k*Z-cd documentation (Version 1.0 May 4, 2021). it can be a way, how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tikz-cd`, only  first few nodes (since contents of others is unknown):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

 
\begin{document}
    \[
\begin{tikzcd}[sep=large]
M   \rar \dar["\mathrm{Pinch}" ' ]
    \drar[dashed, "\beta_1 + \beta_2 + \beta_3 = 0", sloped]
    & * \rar \dar 
        \arrow[dd, phantom, ""{coordinate, name=U}]
        & \Sigma M \rar \dar                                  
            & \Sigma M \dar     
              \arrow[ddlll, dashed,
                  to path={ -- ([xshift=5em]\tikztostart.east)
                            |- ([yshift=-3em]U) [near end]\tikztonodes
                            -| ([xshift=-2em]\tikztotarget.west)
                            -- (\tikztotarget)}]    \\     
M \vee M \vee M \rar[swap, "{(\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3)}" ] 
  \arrow[d, phantom, ""{coordinate, name=V}]
    & N \rar 
         & N' \rar 
            & \Sigma M\vee \Sigma M\vee \Sigma M 
              \arrow[ddlll, "{(\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3)}" ',
                  to path={ -- ([xshift=1em]\tikztostart.east)
                            |- (V) [near end]\tikztonodes
                            -| ([xshift=-3em]\tikztotarget.west)
                            -- (\tikztotarget)}]    \\
* \rar \dar
    & * \rar \dar
        & * \rar[dashed] \dar
            & ~                                     \\
N \rar
        & N' \rar
            & \Sigma M\vee \Sigma M\vee \Sigma M    \rar[dashed]
                & ~
\end{tikzcd}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer, just too long for a comment.  This shows how to use standalone class with pdflatex.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
% \usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}% ???

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[sep=large]
  M \rar \dar["\mathrm{Pinch}" ' ]  \arrow[dr, dashed, "\beta_1 + \beta_2 + \beta_3 = 0", sloped] & * \rar \dar & \Sigma M \dar \rar & \Sigma M \dar \\%
M \vee M \vee M \rar[swap, "{(\beta_1 , \beta_2 , \beta_3)}" ] & N \rar & N' \rar & \Sigma M \vee \Sigma M \vee \Sigma M \rar[swap, "{(\beta_1 , \beta_2 , \beta_3)}" ] & N \rar & N' \rar & \Sigma M \vee \Sigma M \vee \Sigma M 
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

This is how to produce the same diagram (more of less) using a plain tikzpicture.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows.meta,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (A) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=2cm, column sep={3cm,between origins}]{
  M & * & \Sigma M & \Sigma M \\
 M \vee M \vee M & N & N' & \Sigma M \vee \Sigma M \vee \Sigma M \\
 N & N' & \Sigma M \vee \Sigma M \vee \Sigma M \\
};
\draw[->] (A-1-1) -- (A-1-2);
\draw[->] (A-1-2) -- (A-1-3);
\draw[->] (A-1-3) -- (A-1-4);

\draw[->] (A-1-1) -- (A-2-1) node[midway,left] {Pinch};
\draw[->] (A-1-2) -- (A-2-2);
\draw[->] (A-1-3) -- (A-2-3);
\draw[->] (A-1-4) -- (A-2-4);

\draw[dashed,->] (A-1-1) -- (A-2-2) node[midway,above,sloped] {$\beta_1 + \beta_2 + \beta_3 = 0$};

\draw[->] (A-2-1) -- (A-2-2) node[midway,below] {$(\beta_1 , \beta_2 , \beta_3)$};
\draw[->] (A-2-2) -- (A-2-3);
\draw[->] (A-2-3) -- (A-2-4);

\draw[thick,green,->] (A-2-4) |- ($(A-2-4)!0.5!(A-3-1)$)% midway
   node[below, black]{$(\beta_1 , \beta_2 , \beta_3)$}
  -| (A-3-1);

\draw[->] (A-3-1) -- (A-3-2);
\draw[->] (A-3-2) -- (A-3-3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo2]

Comment: So where is the 16 rectangles?

Comment: I should warn you that I know nothing about tikzcd protocol.  I could do the whole thing using tikz, however.

Comment: Ok. I will try the code and let you know if I have further questions.

Comment: your second code did not work with me, I am still having my problem.

Comment: Also, your first code did not work with me, I am still having my problem.

Comment: Are you using pdflatex (latex->pdf) or latex->dvi->ps->pdf (ghostscript)?  The latter adds time and difficulty with each conversion.

Comment: I am using the first.

Comment: Then you definitely don't need the pst packages, as they are for postscript.

Comment: could you please look at this question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600942/drawing-a-very-long-commutative-diagram  I asked it as your code does not give me what I want, I hope this question clarify to you what I want.