# Drawing a very long commutative diagram

Tags: line-breaking, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

Here is the figure I wanna draw:

[image]

In the above figure, the lines are supposed to be either right arrows or down arrows.

Here is the code I am using (which did not work)

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
 \usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}

\[ 
\begin{tikzcd}[sep=large]
  M \rar \dar["\mathrm{Pinch}" ' ]  \arrow[dr, dashed, "\beta_1 + \beta_2 + \beta_3 = 0", sloped] & * \rar \dar & \Sigma M \dar \rar & \Sigma M \dar \\%
M \vee M \vee M \rar[swap, "{(\beta_1 , \beta_2 , \beta_3)}" ] & N \rar & N' \rar & \Sigma M \vee \Sigma M \vee \Sigma M \rar[swap, "{(\beta_1 , \beta_2 , \beta_3)}" ] & N \rar & N' \rar & \Sigma M \vee \Sigma M \vee \Sigma M 
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

I asked the question here [How to make a commutative diagram with 16 rectangles and to take not more than half a page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600069/how-to-make-a-commutative-diagram-with-16-rectangles-and-to-take-not-more-than-h/600179?noredirect=1#comment1505592_600179) but still I do not know how to do it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your code is not even close to showed picture. What you like to have? Code for shoved picture (all arrows are unlabeled)? You are faced with problem "how to put elephant in lady suitcase" :-(

Comment: I will complete the difference between the picture and the code .... I just need a code for the picture @Zarko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a suggestion: The `trail off` key (either with `right` or `left`) will draw an arrow in the given direction that peters out.

Since the second part of the diagram is placed in the same `tikzcd` environment the columns will align. If that's not desired just use multiple `tikzcd` environments.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\tikzcdset{
  trail off main/.style 2 args={
    /tikz/arrows=-,
    /tikz/dash pattern=on 3.5mm off 1mm   on 1.5mm off 1mm
                       on  .5mm off .75mm on  .5mm off .75mm,
    start anchor={#1}, to path={-- ++ (#2:1cm)\tikztonodes}},
  trail off/.default=right, trail off/.is choice,
  trail off/right/.style={trail off main={east}{right}},
  trail off/left/.style={trail off main={west}{left}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large, column sep={7em,between origins}]
  M \rar
    \dar["Pinch"' math mode=false]
    \arrow[dr, dashed, "\beta_1 + \beta_2 + \beta_3 = 0", sloped]
& *        \rar \dar
& \Sigma M \dar \rar
& \Sigma M \dar \ar[trail off]
\\
  M \vee M \vee M \rar["{(\beta_1 , \beta_2 , \beta_3)}"']
& N  \rar
& N' \rar
& \Sigma M \vee \Sigma M \vee \Sigma M
     \ar[trail off,"{(\beta_1 , \beta_2 , \beta_3)}"']
\\
% now comes the right part below it
\ar[trail off=left, <-] X \rar \dar & A \rar \dar & B \dar
\\
\ar[trail off=left, <-, "{(\beta_1 , \beta_2 , \beta_3)}"']
  N  \rar
& N' \rar & \Sigma M \vee \Sigma M \vee \Sigma M 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]